# Alternative to single quote terminators for strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I know in MySQL and a couple of other databases, you can use double quotes and single quotes, but it seems like double quotes are reserved for column names in SQL Server. In PHP, you can use `<<<EOT`s.

I'm writing a ton of queries that only have single quotes in the string values and it is becoming a nuisance to have to escape every single single-quote with an extra single quote. Is there an alternative to single quote terminators for strings?

Comment: In more than 15 years of writing code against SQLserver databases, I can count on the fingers of one hand the times I needed to do that. How are you writing your queries?  You should probably be using parameters instead of strings if this is a problem for you.

Comment: I'm just writing them in ssms. Long story short, we're in the process of writing a tool to do this, but in the meantime, I have to enter data in directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF`. After that, you can use double quotes for strings. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) for details.